# Python: listing callable objects?

Tags: python, callable

I am trying to list only callable objects but I seem to be doing something wrong. For example,

```
>>> [m for m in dir({}) if callable(getattr({},m))]
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
```

However, this is wrong, for example `{}.__doc__` is clearly a string, etc. What is wrong with my list comprehension

Comment: According to [Built-in Functions - callable](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#callable) you shouldn't trust the `True` return value of the function as it can return `True` for non-callable objects. If it returns `False` however, it's definitively not callable.

Comment: By the way, your list comprehension only returns callable objects in *Python 2.7*. I don't get `__doc__`

Comment: You say "this is wrong" and mention `__doc__`, but your list doesn't include `__doc__`?

Comment: Well that's embarrassing - I didn't notice. All the items in your list is in fact callable, @yayu

Comment: If you want something different, like all methods on a class, you can do way better with `inspect`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code as written is the best Python has to offer.  You mention it being wrong because of `__doc__`, but your list doesn't include `__doc__`.  I think you already have working code.